# What if there are 'N' numbers of microservices then do we have to configure them all manually in Zuul Api Gateway?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

Suppose we have zuul api gateway and there are n no for microservices co, in that case, how do we route to all the microservice? Do we have to write their configuration manually in the properties file of api gateway?

`for example

```
zuul:
 prefix: /api  
    routes:  
     defects-service:  
      path: /defects-service/**  
       serviceId: defects-service`
```

Do we have to write this in the **application.properties** file for all the microservices?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Eureka (Discovery service)** along with Zuul, you don't need to manually give all the routes in Zuul. Instead, **Zuul will scan the eureka registry** and get all the registered applications

And make sure that you have these two properties set in your zuul server

```
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
```

Comment: ok, and through URL  we can call whichever microservice we want which are registered in eureka right?    first address of the ports where API gateway is running then /  name of the service/path mentioned in the controller